# show complete edit text when it is clicked

Tags: android

I have a edit text and i want to push it up when user click on it. that is it should be completely visible to user. 
Now the problem is when i write some line and my keyboard is visible , then if i again click on edittext then only first line is visible . 
here is my onClickListner of edittext....

```
 content.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    scrollView.scrollTo(0, send.getTop()); //send is a button place below edittext.

                }
            };
            scrollView.postDelayed(r, 200);

        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "push it up"? Like, the keyboard popping up when the EditText is focused?

Comment: I want to make whole edittext visible when keyboard appears

Comment: Could you post the whole XML file containing the EditText? That'd help out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your manifest, in the activity where you want this to happen.

`<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">`

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden|adjustPan"